# Changing a text in a Text file with C#

Tags: c#

in my program, user names and passwords are coming from text files. I want to update the password by pressing a button when necessary, what can I do for this?

[image]

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.IsMdiContainer = true;

        string[] firmalar = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\sirket.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in firmalar)
        {
            SirketList.Items.Add(str);
        }

        string[] kullanici = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\kullanici.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in kullanici)
        {
            KullaniciList.Items.Add(str);
        }

        string[] kod = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\kod.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in kod)
        {
            kodList.Items.Add(str);
        }
        string[] sistem = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\sistem.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in sistem)
        {
            sistemList.Items.Add(str);
        }
        string[] isveren = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\isveren.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in isveren)
        {
            isverenList.Items.Add(str);
        }
        string[] araci = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\\araci.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        foreach (string str in araci)
        {
            ListAraci.Items.Add(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Comment: I suggest that you learn to read and write a single XML or JSON file - or even CSV. This single-file-per-property stuff is a bit nuts.

Comment: I don't understand how this UI will work. When you select another item in one of comboboxes - what will happen with other? You can simply use DataGridView and load the same data in table.

Answer (score 2):

[File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-6.0) static class is your friend here.

Seems you use different files for each one of the properties you want to load/save, so you should bind to your save button code that looks like this:

```
public static async Task SavePasswordAsync()
{
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(kodList, text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would store all this information in a single file. And the data would be located line by line. Then I would read it by dividing it by lines as I read, change the new value and rewrite it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I rolled back your edit because the site you linked to was not in English. Surely you can find a better resource?

Comment: Since the questioner is Turkish, I provided a Turkish source.Can we undo the edit?

Comment: The OP's preferred language is not really relevant. Content on the site is required to be in English only, and links to external sources should generally be in English as well.